# Function that returns all the elements where field is 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the array:

```
var tabs = [
    {"id": 1, "Name": "Top", "Paris": 1, "London": 1, "Rome": 1},
    {"id": 2, "Name": "Best", "Paris": 1, "London": 0, "Rome": 0},
    {"id": 3, "Name": "Cheap", "Paris": 0, "London": 1, "Rome": 0}
];
```

How can I write a function that receives as argument one of the towns (London or Paris or Rome) different each time and returns the elements of the array which the argument is 1? For example, I want to take all the elements where `London=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var tabs= [

{ "id": 1, "Name": "Top","Paris":1,"London":1, "Rome":1},
{ "id": 2, "Name": "Best","Paris":1,"London":0,"Rome":0},
{ "id": 3, "Name": "Cheap","Paris":0,"London":1,"Rome":0}

];

var getElementsWith=function(array,name){
  var myElements=[];
  array.forEach(function(tab){
    if(tab[name]===1)
      myElements.push(tab);
  });
  return myElements;
  };

console.log(getElementsWith(tabs,"Paris"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter`:

```
function filterList(cityName) {
    return tabs.filter(function(o) {
        return o[cityName] === 1;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic function, which takes the array, key and value, you are looking for. Then use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for the sub set.

```js
function filter(array, key, value) {
    return array.filter(function (object) {
        return object[key] === value;
    });
}

var tabs = [{ "id": 1, "Name": "Top","Paris":1,"London":1, "Rome":1 },{ "id": 2, "Name": "Best","Paris":1,"London":0,"Rome":0 },{ "id": 3, "Name": "Cheap","Paris":0,"London":1,"Rome":0 }],
    result = filter(tabs, 'London', 1);

console.log(result);
```